# Add a New Control on Top Most of Others - C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a loading panel in my form for some seconds.
The loading panel is a user control so I add and load it like this:

```
        var ct = new UcLoader { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        this.Controls.Add(ct);
        ct.BringToFront();
```

in my main form, I have a button docked on top. When I add this loader and then bring it to the front, the button is still visible on top of the form.

If I put the main form's button inside a panel (the button is docked top in the panel) and then making the panel to docked fill, and then I load the Loader control it will work WELL. it will hide the form's controls and It will stay on top of all.

But I do not want to add all of the main form's controls inside a panel and then doing this.

How to force the new control to force Fill the whole form?

Updated:

Here by `form`, I mean every container control, a form itself, or a panel.

Comment: Have you tried `SendToBack()` instead? Btw, you can anchor the Button.

Comment: If I `SendToBack` the button and then `BringToFront` the loader it will work. But just think about a bunch of controls inside the form, then I must SendToBack and handle the controls docking.

Comment: Yep, I forgot you have a Button there. Don't dock the UC, just `BringToFront()` it and `ct.Bounds = this.ClientRectangle;` Or use an overlay, probably better, to avoid  quirks (some really proud controls do not like to be overlapped by others).

Comment: Call the form's Update() method so you can be sure the panel is actually painted before you hang the UI thread.  Do always avoid hanging the UI thread.

Comment: Of course, if the Form can be resized in the meanwhile, anchor the UC to all sides. The `OnLoad` method / `Load` event is a good place for that code (so the Form is already setup).

Comment: is there any way to show me the whole code?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this:

```
var ct = new UcLoader();
ct.Size = this.Size; // To cover the whole form
this.Controls.Add(ct);
ct.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Remember to anchor it: `ct.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;`. Otherwise, if the Form is resized, the UC will not follow. Also, set `ct.Bounds = this.ClientRectangle;`: the Size is not enough, the Location also matters (yes, you may say, it's `(0, 0)`, but...). Anchor after you have set the bounds. + Specify where this code should be placed.

Comment: Also, note that Size and ClientSize are not the same thing :)

Comment: @Jimi it will work with your notes if I add the loader into a form, But If I want to add the loader inside a specific panel (container) control, using `anchor` property will cause not showing the loader, and If I do not use the anchor, the loader will not cover the whole panel.

Comment: Absolutely not. If you want to use a Panel as the container for the UC, then set the Bounds of the Panel and anchor it as described. Add the Panel to the Form.Controls and `BringToFront()` it. Then, add the UC to the Panel and Dock->Fill it. Do this in OnLoad or Form.Load, not in the Form constructor.

Comment: @Jimi that panel is already filled with some controls and it is already docked right in the form, By clicking on a button, I must load the UC into the panel as the topmost control. so with the instructions you told, I did not succeed :(

Comment: First of all, this is not what you're describing in your question, then, it's **exactly the same thing**. Do you have a Panel docked (or whatever) to the Form and you want to show the UC inside this Panel? Then, as described, set the `UC.Bounds = [The Panel].ClientRectangle`, anchor the UC to all sides, add the UC to `[The Panel].Controls` and `UC.BringToFront()`.

Comment: @Jimi solved :) I was using `UC.Bounds = [Its Container].Bounds` instead of ÷UC.Bounds = [Its Container].ClientRectangle. If you add it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @tontonsevilla Would you pick up these notes and update your answer accordingly? I'll delete these comments after.